# Customize WebAPI "Access Denied" response

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an ASP.net WebAPI application with OAUTH 2.0 authentication with separated STS (token service) and custom JSON formatter (ServiceStack.Text).

I'm trying to customize the access denied object/message to make it homogeneous with the rest of error messages but i haven't found a way to change it.

I'm also thinking that in this case is used the default formatter.

Example:

```
{
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Example result:

```
{
  "message": "... insert error message here ...",
  "details": null
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can return a custom response for the current `HttpActionContext` using a class for which you can define its members.

```
            public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                    bool isAuthenticated = IsAuthenticated(actionContext);

                    if (!isAuthenticated)
                    {
                        actionContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse<CustomActionResult>(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new CustomActionResult
                        {
                            Message = "... insert error message here ...",
                            Details = null
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            public class CustomActionResult
            {
                public string Message { get; set; }
                public string Details { get; set; }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but how does it act on an API without authentication?

Comment: You can define your own logic for authenticating the web api requests in this method - IsAuthenticated(), this has to be specific to your application's requirement. I didn't posted my logic cos that is relevant to my application and may not be useful to you. You know when the API request should be denied as unauthorized and when it should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To change all 'Access Denied' messages for your entire ASP.NET web site, you can create a HttpModule for all not authorized status returned from your site.  In the HttpModule you can handle the EndRequest event and you can check the response.StatusCode if it is 401 you can change the message to anything you want.  Like so:

```
    public class AuthorizeMsgModule : IHttpModule
    {            
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {                
            context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
        }


        // If the request was unauthorized, modify the response sent to the user
        private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                response.ClearContent();
                response.Write("{\"message\": \"... insert error message here ...\",\"details\": null}");                    
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

Register your module in your web.config for example:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="AuthorizeMsgModule" type="mynamespace.AuthorizeMsgModule, myassembly" />
</modules>
```

This will give you the content you write any time you return a 401 status.  As you can see here in fiddler.

[image: fiddler]